# using IFilter with x86 Application

Tags: c#, .net, x86, ifilter

I have developed an Application which needs compiled as x86 because it uses a component which is only available as x86-version. My Application uses IFilter to get contents of Files.
Now, I need also x86-Versions of IFilter - even my application runs on ax x64 machine. I have found it for Office-Applications. But not for PDF and RTF. Does someone know, where I can get this filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe has an x64 PDF IFilter available for download. (The Adobe x86 PDF IFilter is bundled with Adobe Acrobat 9 and Adobe Reader 9.)  http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025

FoxIt has a multi-threaded PDF IFilter both x86 and x64 for sale. (There is a 30 day trial download available.) You can search for "foxitsoftware" and "IFilter"

I have no real RTF IFilter experience, but regarding RTF IFilters you can check Praveen Agrawal's directions in:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointecm/thread/21b1705f-eb7c-480b-8c11-35c6a5d965ab